# docker-compose --abort-on-container-exit doesn't stop tor services

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use a tor docker service, which is working in my docker-compose file

```
services:
  tor:
    image: dockurr/tor
  my_task:
    image: ...
```

I run this with `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit` and when `my_task` exits (as expected) the output is

```
tmp_my_task_1 exited with code 0
Aborting on container exit...
Stopping tmp_tor_1     ... done
```

Then it hangs. I can ctrl-c to kill it, but how can I make docker-compose forcibly kill the tor service to exit when `my_task` exits?